# Evernote Developers Support Inquiry: Transfer subscription to Sandbox account

Tags: evernote

I'd like to transfer my subscription to my sandbox account so I can run my own tools using the API. I need to have this subscription transferred to my sandbox account. (I had this done last year, and I think I just have to ask for it each year.)

Asking a question on SO seems like the wrong way to file a support ticket, but this is what I was instructed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run your tool on your production account?

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by transferring your subscription to your sandbox account. If you want to upgrade your account on sandbox for some testing purpose, here's what you should do: http://dev.evernote.com/support/faq.php#sandboxpremium